# Howto create WSO2 DAS event receiver using management API

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

Once you set HideAdminServiceWSDLs to false on carbon configuration file is posible to discover the EventReceiverAdminService service endpoint. It expose the deployEventReceiverConfiguration method. Could anyone provide an example on howto use this service in a multi-tenant context? I try calling the service but every time I get the following response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>unknown</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and no usefull message on the DAS logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the XML configuration of the event receiver. I tried the following with SOAP UI and it works.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:adm="http://admin.receiver.event.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <adm:deployEventReceiverConfiguration>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <adm:eventReceiverConfigXml><![CDATA[<eventReceiver xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventreceiver" name="httpReceiver" statistics="disable" trace="disable">
   <from eventAdapterType="http">
      <property name="transports">all</property>
   </from>
   <mapping customMapping="disable" type="json" />
   <to streamName="org.wso2.event.sensor.stream" version="1.0.0" />
</eventReceiver>]]>
```

In a multi tenant environment, use the respective tenant admin's  credentials for basic authentication. Then it will deploy the event receiver in the correct tenant. When deploying DAS will print a log as follows,

```
[2016-02-11 17:40:39,670] admin@test.com [1] [DAS] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@test.com [1]' logged in at [2016-02-11 17:40:39,670-0700]
[2016-02-11 17:40:39,674] admin@test.com [1] [DAS] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.util.helper.EventReceiverConfigurationFileSystemInvoker} -  Event receiver configuration saved to the filesystem :httpReceiver.xml
[2016-02-11 17:40:39,675] admin@test.com [1] [DAS] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.core.internal.InputAdapterRuntime} -  Connecting receiver httpReceiver
[2016-02-11 17:40:39,676] admin@test.com [1] [DAS] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.stream.core.internal.EventJunction} -  Producer added to the junction. Stream:BAM_MESSAGE_TRACE:1.0.0
[2016-02-11 17:40:39,676] admin@test.com [1] [DAS] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.EventReceiverDeployer} -  Event Receiver configuration successfully deployed and in active state: httpReceiver
```